# How to make a dependent drop down in C# Visual?

Tags: c#-4.0

I’m using C# Visual. I have 2 combo boxes; one is for supplier list and and another one for invoice list. I want when I select the particular supplier the other combo box list add on another all the invoices of the particular supplier.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please put that code in the question also, using the formatting tools provided. It is very helpful to show that, as it will give readers a good idea of your current thinking, and will show that you're willing to help yourself as much as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact names but essentially you need to create an event for when your "supplier" value is changed. In this event you would need to load your invoice list,  clear the "invoice" items and then populate the items of the invoice combo box with your fresh list.